# Show SnackBar on modal inside modal

Tags: flutter

My condition is i have modal inside modal, using `showModalBottomSheet`, we can call it first modal then second modal. I want to show `ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar` on second modal, but when i trigger it, it appear only on first modal. Of course i use the context of second modal.

```
showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    isScrollControlled: true,
    shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
    ),
    clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    builder: (_) => BlocProvider.value(
      value: BlocProvider.of<ShowPostBloc>(context),
      child: SecondModal(),
    ),
  );

ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Hallo')));
```

Can anyone explain it, why this is happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Scaffold()` for first and second modal, SnackBar will appear on both modal.

Comment: I thinking it should show for the latest one 

Comment: @Md.YeasinSheikh : But when i show SnackBar on second modal then directly i close the modal. In first modal, the SnackBar still showing.